# a particular image without css style

Tags: css, wordpress

is that I installed a wordpress plugin to add frames and shadows to images, but there is a particular image that I do not want to apply the shadow and the frame, but with the plugin goes with frame and shadow. How could I avoid this? thanks

The plugin:

Plugin Name: WP Image Borders
Description: WP Image Borders makes it easy to add or remove image borders from pictures in your blog posts. 
Version: 1.4.6
Author: Ben Sibley
Author URI: http://profiles.wordpress.org/bensibley
License: GPLv2

Comment: you can add a `class` to override the wordpress css

Comment: Can you post a live link or code to the question in issue ?? - @Julia

Comment: Hello Might you be more specific? I get confused easily, thanks

Comment: Nathan Sorry plugin code is very extensive

Comment: @Julia can you give a CSS code that applies on image?

Comment: Ok I will look for one second

Comment: I do not see the css style plugin :_s I edit the post whit info

Comment: Remove the `!important` bit in the plugin file, and you can create a new class, called `.no-border` in your CSS file, and add it to your image, and the class would be something like `img.no-border { border:0 none !important; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the plugin `.php` file:

**Replace**

```
echo '<style type="text/css" media="screen">.wib-img img { 
   border-style: ' . $options["bs_wib_border_style"] . ' !important; 
   border-width: ' . $options["bs_wib_border_width"] . 'px !important; 
   border-radius: ' . $options["bs_wib_border_radius"] . 'px !important;
   border-color: ' . $options["bs_wib_border_color"] . ' !important; 
   -moz-box-shadow: ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_horizontal"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_vertical"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_blur"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_spread"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_color"] . ' !important; 
   -webkit-box-shadow: ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_horizontal"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_vertical"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_blur"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_spread"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_color"] . ' !important; 
   box-shadow: ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_horizontal"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_vertical"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_blur"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_spread"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_color"] . ' !important; 
   } </style>';
```

**With**

```
echo '<style type="text/css" media="screen">.wib-img img { 
   border-style: ' . $options["bs_wib_border_style"] . '; 
   border-width: ' . $options["bs_wib_border_width"] . 'px; 
   border-radius: ' . $options["bs_wib_border_radius"] . 'px;
   border-color: ' . $options["bs_wib_border_color"] . '; 
   -moz-box-shadow: ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_horizontal"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_vertical"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_blur"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_spread"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_color"] . '; 
   -webkit-box-shadow: ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_horizontal"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_vertical"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_blur"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_spread"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_color"] . '; 
   box-shadow: ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_horizontal"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_vertical"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_blur"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_spread"] . 'px ' . $options["bs_wib_box_shadow_color"] . '; 
   } </style>';
```

Here we remove the `!important` bit from the plugin.

In your `.CSS` file, add:

```
img.no-border { border:0 none !important; }
```

Then in your post, you can have

```
<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-6 no-border" alt="" src="your-image-here.jpg" width="300" height="225" />
<img class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-9" alt="" src="your-image-here.jpg" width="300" height="225" />
```

**NOTE**: make sure that you add `no-border` to the `img` - where you don't want a border to appear.

The first image will use the border from the plugin, and the 2nd image will have no border.

Comment: Great, ¿and the shadow? :O

Comment: For the shadow, just add `-webkit-box-shadow: none; -moz-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none;` to the `.no-border` class, you'll probably have to add `!important` to them as well.

Comment: Great, great thousand times great. Thank you!